# AVG Remote Admin installing Trial AVG Internet Security

Tags: windows-7

My company has been using AVG Remote Administrator for a few years now, but over the past couple months, I've noticed a weird issue when doing a remote install.

Due to circumstances beyond my control (there was a strike for the employees), many systems were not in the building to connect to our server to get a new key for AVG Antivirus Business Edition 2012/2013. The strike is now over, and machines are coming in because their protection expired (as expected).

I get the computer name, and punch it into the Remote Admin console, and try to do a remote install. I put in the domain Admin username/password, choose the options I want, choose a Hidden Installation, and watch the progress. The key I entered is our AVG Antivirus Business Edition key, which works on other systems too.

When the install is finished, even if I choose the option to download the latest AVG AV package, it is installing a *trial* version of AVG Internet Security.

As an experiment, I booted up an old image to a new machine, which had no AVG installed. I pushed the install, with the same settings, to that PC, and AVG AV installed, no issues. I also tried uninstalling all AVG related entries in the Programs and Features section, and rebooting before trying again on the other systems. As a last resort, I tried to copy the Install directory to a USB flash drive (following the wizard), and running the `avgsetup.bat` file as the Administrator, and the same effect: no AV, just the IS.

What am I doing wrong? What can I do to get AVG to remote install on these workstations? There will be about a hundred more I need to do, and I would prefer to NOT have to touch every workstation.

Comment: I've had strange problems with the Admin tool as well. Not for nothing but if you have a valid license then you have valid support. I would open a support case with them to figure it out.

Comment: Chat is down (even though it's within their open time), so I sent an email request. I'll post the solution here if I get one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I got through to the tech support. It's a known issue with some techs, not with others. The general consensus is, the way the install was pushed out was wrong.

In the console, I needed to go into the Advanced Network Installation wizard. On the first page, I need to choose the first option, to use the console for installing (not download for network install). On the second step, tell it to download the latest files. Then, proceed as per normal. This worked on 2 separate systems, with a brand new image, and with the old expired AVG installation.

The reason it normally doesn't work with systems that have had AVG previously installed *and the license expired more than 14 days* is that it is told to disconnect from the Console after that time out. It will not accept any communications with it. There was a program released by AVG that allows you to install a new license key, via login script or GPO (although it requires Administrator rights, so login script didn't work for me). Once it has a new key, it will connect back up to the console, and allow you to update to the latest version of that AVG.